# get sum of width of previous elements until particular element

Tags: jquery, width, jquery-ui-resizable

i am trying to make splittable row columns using jquery ui-resizable. so here i need to get sum of the width of previous divisions of which is resizing. below is what i tried. but here `if(cells[0] === currentSpan[0])` is not working.. any helps please. And if i can get this sum of div widths without a `each` will be great..

**HTML**

```
<div class='row'>
   <div class='simpleSpan' style='width:50px'></div>
   <div class='simpleSpan' style='width:10px'></div>
   <div class='simpleSpan' style='width:20px'></div>//this one will be re-sizing
   <div class='simpleSpan' style='width:20px'></div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
 var appendRow = $('.row');
 $(".report .simpleSpan").resizable({
    handles: 'e',
    minWidth: '50',
    maxWidth: '500',
    resize: function() {
        var totWidth = 0;
        var currentSpan = this;
        $(appendRow).each(function(x,span) 
        {
            var cells = $(".simpleSpan", span);
            for(iCounter=0;iCounter<cells.length;iCounter++)
            {
                if(cells[0] === currentSpan[0])
                    return false;
                totWidth = totWidth + cells.width();
            }
        });
        alert(totWidth);
    },


  });
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ff9vp99g/1/) what you want?

Comment: @anpsmn not exactly.. i want only sum of width of above sibling of `this` no need below siblings.. `totWidth` should result 60.. any idea?

Comment: Replace `.siblings()` with `.prevAll()`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ff9vp99g/2/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess this'll help you http://jsfiddle.net/un353ab6/1/

```
var widthAdd = 0;
var lengthPreDiv = $('.get').prevAll().length;
for(i=0; i<lengthPreDiv; i++)
{
    widthAdd = widthAdd+parseInt($('.get').siblings().eq(i).width());
}
alert(widthAdd);
```